# Can we not know all prime numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, infinity

I found [this](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Beyond_Infinity/EPQ8DgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) in *Beyond Infinity* by Eugenia Cheng:

> We can’t list all the numbers in the world because there are infinitely many. Nor can we list all the prime numbers in the world, but for a different reason – we don’t know what they are. (But if we did, we still wouldn't be able to list them as there are infinitely many.

I couldn't understand why we can't know prime numbers.

I understand that there are infinite prime numbers. But that can't be a reason to say that that we don't know what they are, right?

(If we had enough computing power, nothing is stoping us from calculating primes, isn't it?)

Because if that was the case, it could also be said that we don't know all numbers in the world as well, right?

So I guess there's something else.

What could it be?

Comment: Maybe he's saying that there is no simple formula for these nth prime number

Comment: With enough computing power, yes we could in theory continuously run a number sieve and find as many prime numbers as we wish and begin writing the list of them.  This has already been done to a certain point.  I think the point is that unlike in the case of just listing the natural numbers $1,2,3,4,5,\dots$ where it is easy to determine the next natural number in the sequence and requires very little effort, it can be tremendously difficult to find the next prime number in the sequence after a certain point.

Comment: Well, this all very vague and informal.  What does it mean to "know" a number?  Does it require that you have specifically thought about that exact number?  Is there some other way to "know" the number?  Whatever the definition (if there even is one), I expect the authors would certainly agree that "we don't know all the numbers in the world".

Comment: It's an informal book meant for non-math people. I guess that explains the vagueness.
But when I saw that I thought there was something to it. I guess there isn't. :)

Comment: We can eventually find all prime numbers , but we need infinite time to compute them, so there won't be a time where we actually know all. Moreover, we cannot even store all $300$-digit primes , for example , since they would not fit in the observable universe.

Comment: We can even list eventually all natural numbers , even all algebraic numbers. There is no difference in the "difficulty" to write down all prime number and all numbers. Both processes require infinite time anyway and also we will hit a brickwall when it comes to note (or even describe) the numbers.

Comment: With regards to "*we can't list ___ because there are infinitely many*"  We can't ever write a complete list.  We *can* however for both of these begin writing a list and write as large of the beginning of the list (*up to a finite amount, subject to physical constraints*) as we wish with a method to always continue the list and if we continued long enough we would be guaranteed to reach any specific number desired.  The natural numbers are what we call "*countable.*"  Compare this to sets of numbers like the reals which are *uncountable*, we couldn't begin such a list that lists everything.

Comment: And in fact, finding huge primes is extremely difficult ! The largest known has still less than $10^8$ digits. To find a $10^{10^{100}}$ digit prime is utterly hopeless in practice although in principal nothing prevents us to do it.

Answer (score 4):

With respect, I do not agree with the author here. There is a rigorous formal definition of what it means to be able to list a sequence $a_n$ of numbers, and it means you can write down a computer program that outputs the members of that list; formally, that the function $n \mapsto a_n$ is [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function). And the sequence $n \mapsto p_n$ of prime numbers is perfectly computable, e.g. using the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

I also do not agree that we don't know what the prime numbers are. Again, there's a rigorous formal definition of what it means to know a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ of numbers, and it means you can write down a computer program that outputs "yes" if some number belongs to that set and "no" if it doesn't; formally, that the set is [computable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_set). And the set of prime numbers is again computable (note that this is a different statement from the above statement); this is exactly the statement that there exist computable primality tests, and e.g. [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) qualifies.

In both of theses cases instead of "computable" you could ask for "efficiently computable" but primality testing is pretty efficient both [in practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) and [in theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test).

Overall I would argue that in most senses that we "know" what the natural numbers are, it's also true that we "know" what the prime numbers are.

An example of a set of numbers I would argue we genuinely don't know is the set of [Fermat primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number); as far as I know we don't have an efficient algorithm for testing whether a Fermat number $F_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$ is prime, basically because they grow too fast, e.g. according to Wikipedia it seems we don't know whether $F_{33}$ is prime. We also don't know whether the set is finite or infinite.

Comment: Minor comment about the GNFS link:  that's for factoring, not primality testing.

Comment: Ah, thanks, replaced it with a link to Baillie-PSW.

Comment: Correct : There is nothing better than Pepin's test for the Fermat numbers and if I remember right we do not even know whether infinite many of them are composite. Odds are extremely good that there is no further Fermat prime (I heard from a careful analysis and the result was something like $1:10^{9}$) and the smallest unknown case is the "monster" $F_{33}$.

Comment: One additional remark : Before we would reach ranges where a computer would need significant time to test the primality , we would have to write up so many primes that this would already take an eternity. So , even considering the difficulty to determine primes, the author's argument is more than debatable.